# Keep my symfony2 bundles decoupled

Tags: symfony, doctrine, bundle

I have two different bundle:

- first bundle, *OrderBundle*  , has core logic and functionalities and contains the Order entity.
- second bundle, *CustomerBundle* depends on OrderBundle and contains the Customer entity.

I need to create a oneToMany relation between Customers and Orders (obviously one Customer do many Orders) but I need to keep the first bundle *OrderBundle* decoupled from the second, because OrderBundle is intended to be reused for other stuff.

I think the correct way could be something like this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html but I can't figure out how to have a concrete implementation.

How to implement the relation between Order and Customer, if I can't specifically use Customer like targetEntity in the ManyToOne doctrine mapping?

Many thanks, in advance.

**UPDATE**

I write down the involved code, for better explanation.

```
\\ Order\Bundle\Entity\Order.php

class Order {   
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order\Bundle\Model\OrderSubjectInterface", inversedBy="orders")
     * @var SourceSubjectInterface
     */
     protected $subject;    // How to define getter ans setter for $subject ? Do I
                               have to use php app/console doctrine:generate:entities command?
     ...



\\ Customer\Bundle\Entity\Customer.php
use Order\Bundle\Model\OrderSubjectInterface;

class Customer implements OrderSubjectInterface{
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Order\Bundle\Entity\Order", mappedBy="subject")
     */
     private $orders;
```

How to define getters, setters and the interface?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the right way.

As shown in the documentation you mentioned, you can specify something like `OrderSubjectInterface` as a targetEntity in the ManyToOne mapping.

This way, you know that your Order is related to subjects. Those subjects are, in your case, the Customers, as defined in `app/config/config.yml`.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite hard to entirely decouple the bundles if you have entity definitions all over the place. The problem is, the Doctrine doesn't allow by default for a related entity to be missing. Let's start from the beginning.

If you want to decouple only Order entity, what you have to do is create interfaces for all its related entities (they need to implement them) and then use the ResolveTargetEntity. So instead of referencing the full entities you reference the interfaces (when you define the relations in your entities). Lastly, you can then set which interface maps to which entity in the configuration.

What this does is it allows you to pick up the Order bundle and put it in an environment which has entirely different entity structure. The important thing is that the entities related to Order must not be missing in the new environment (They can be entirely different, but they must implement the same interfaces as the originals). Then you change the settings so that the interfaces point to the entities from the new environment.

So as you see, this is not "entirely decoupled" code. I can't help you much more without some details. Is the relation bidirectional or unidirectional? What do you exactly mean by "reused for other stuff", can you be more detailed?

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I'll try to be more detailed:
I would like a bidiractional relation and saying 'reused for other stuff' means that OrderBundle should be used by other bundles, without Customer relation. So I need no direct mention of Customer in OrderBundle.
I would like OrderBundle with no explicit mapped relation; CustomerBundle depends on OrderBundle so relation colud be implemented there.

Hope to be clear enough (with my bad english).

Comment: So you mean to use the OrderBundle in other Symfony projects which won't have the CustomerBundle present? Or do you mean you want to use the solely in this one project, but should be available for use in other bundles? Because in the latter case you don't need much decoupling, it's already usable from other bundles and Customer is already present, so no worries. But I suspect it's the former case. In this case the best you can do is make the Customer entity implement CustomerInterface and then use ResolveTargetEntity. But note you'll still have to have a dummy Customer entity.

Comment: Also, check out a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545157/how-do-do-optional-cross-bundle-associations-in-symfony-2) (a hack, basically) which I rigged up some time ago. It's a dirty hack which basically silences or skips the thrown missing entity exception when the interface is not being tied to an entity. This way you will have a relation in the entity, but it will not be present in the database (no dummy table). It's not widely tested, though, but it works for me.

Comment: I have a _standalone_ OrderBundle that must be reused in an other Symfony project where I need a relation with CustomerBundle. OrderBundle is installable via composer from a private SVN repo, so I think I can't define an explicit relation with CustomerBundle in the 'standalone' project.
So the use case are:
PROJECT A: Only OrderBundle
PROJECT B: OrderBundle + CustomerBundle (customer has oneToMany relation with orders)